# Parse url from javascript popup in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am developing web app using ASP.NET and i am also using javascript in the gridview header as TemplateField to open a window like this,

```
<a href="javascript:var popup = window.open('PopUp.aspx?+Value','Popup','width=200,height=200');
```

What I need to do in the "PopUp.aspx" code behind is to parse "Value" from "PopUp.aspx?+Value" in order for display a text based the value of "Value".

How do I get the "Popup.aspx?+Value from the PopUp.aspx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using query string parameters:

`PopUp.aspx?param=value` and in PopUp.aspx: `var value = Request["param"];` to retrieve the value.